# Why this two code blocks are equivalent for Option class?

Tags: scala, scala-option

[In documentation of Option class](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option) written that following two examples are equivalent:

```
val name: Option[String] = request getParameter "name"
val upper = name map { _.trim } filter { _.length != 0 } map { _.toUpperCase }
println(upper getOrElse "")
```

and

```
val upper = for {
  name <- request getParameter "name"
  trimmed <- Some(name.trim)
  upper <- Some(trimmed.toUpperCase) if trimmed.length != 0
} yield upper
println(upper getOrElse "")
```

But I don't understand how they can be equivalent: in first code block `request getParameter "name"` return instance of type `Option[String]`, but in second code block statement `name <- request getParameter "name"` return instance of type `String` (I assumed  that because next statement calls `trim` method on `name` variable (`trim` is not defined for `Option[String]`)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conversion from `for ... yield` comprehension to `map`/`flatMap` method calls is done by the compiler. It's not required that the `Option` is an `Iterable`; the only thing necessary in this case is `Option` having `map` / `flatMap` methods:

- `flatMap` if there are more `->` calls after it in the same `for` block
- `map` if it's the last one

We can create our own `MyOption` class like this:

```
case class MyOption[+T](value: T) {
  def flatMap[A](f: T => MyOption[A]): MyOption[A] = f(value)
  def map[A](f: T => A): MyOption[A] = MyOption(f(value))
  override def toString = s"Some($value)"
}
```

Then:

```
val result = for {
  a <- MyOption("one")
  b <- MyOption("two")
} yield a + "," + b
println(result)
// prints: Some(one,two)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Option` is an [`Iterable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterable%24) (there's an implicit `option2Iterable` method in `Option` companion object), that's why it can be used in `someVar <- someOption` clause. In fact, that arrow means "take elements from collection on the right".

So you're right, `name` in the 2nd example is a `String`.

In the 1st one you can see there are `map` and other `Iterable` methods used on `Option`. It is basically the same as `for` expression below, but calls methods directly, while `for` is just a syntax sugar and gets translated into the chain of method calls by the compiler.

Comment: So `Iterable` instance (returned after implicit conversion using `option2Iterable`) will contain only one element if `Option` is not empty (i.e. `Option == Some`), or returned `Iterable` will not contain any elements if `Option` is `None`?